# How to change UIView constraints based on device orientation using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I am trying to create `iOS` `storyboard` with multiple view for `portrait` and `landscape`. Everything I have created storyboard `constraints` and `autolayout`.

Now my problem is for portrait I need to show like below portrait Image. Thats I have done by using storyboard constraints.

For landscape Need to show `First View (red)` and bottom bar only other I have hidden by hardcode. But I don't know how to expand the red screen first view full height upto bottom bar top.

NOTE : This is Universal App.

```
- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    UIDevice * device = note.object;
    switch(device.orientation)
    {
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            /* start special animation */
            NSLog(@"Portrait");
            self.namelist_tableview.hidden = NO;// ORANGE VIEW
            break;

        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            /* start special animation */
            NSLog(@"Landscape");
            self.namelist_tableview.hidden = YES;// ORANGE VIEW
            break;

        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            /* start special animation */
            NSLog(@"Landscape");
            self.namelist_tableview.hidden = YES;// ORANGE VIEW
            break;

        default:
            break;
    };
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple, add constrains in intefacebuilder for portrait mode ,
 add constrains for landscape mode.
Next make an outlet for all constrains.
In device change orientation event do this

**if you are in landscape mode**

+Set active constrains for portrait to false (constraint.active = NO)

+Set active of constrains for landscape to true (constraint.active = YES)

**if you are in portrait mode**

+Set active of constrains for landscape to false (constraint.active = NO)

+Set active of constrains for portrait to true (constraint.active = YES)

Answer (score 1):

you can add the red view height constraint, store it in your `UIViewController`.
when the device's orientation changed. if portrait, set the ret view height constraint equal how long you want to set, and landscape set the red view height constraint your initial value.

Comment: Sorry I cant get you. Just give me a constarint attribute code for that red view.Please give some code @tutu_magi

Answer (score 1):

It can be done easily if you use size classes.

Use cmd+delete for the views which you don't want in landscape mode.and set others accordingly.

[image: DISPLAY IMAGE 1]

[image: DISPLAY IMAGE 2]

Comment: I am using size class only. sorry I cant get you. Could you please give some samples @sourav

Comment: Thank you for sharing that video btw why we need to create seperate storyboard for different size of devices. Usually If we create more storyboard It will complex ur app development. My problem is for portrait U can see above screen like I want to create and If I turn Landscape that red should be show full height of device and orange should 0. That is my scenario plz help me!@sourav

Comment: i have done the same thing. and i am unable to post the screenshots of mine as am having low reputation point .

Comment: so is there any restriction to use size classes ?

Comment: @souravYes. You can see exactly what I am trying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087254/auto-layout-view-to-fullscreen-on-rotate

Comment: Buddy U pasted ur local path @sourav

Answer (score 0):

If you did not fix the height of the red view than you can do something like this:

Create a instance of height constraint of the yellow color view like,

> Step 1: Select height constraint as I did
>   [image]

-

> Step 2: Make a instance in you view controller interface
>   [image]

After that write below line of code to your `orientationChanged:` method
`self.heightConstarintYelloView.constant = 0.f;`

**It will set you yellow box height to zero and because of the vertical spacing between red view and yellow view, red view will than expand.**

Comment: can you please post yellow and red view with screen shoot!@Vijay

Comment: your solution working for iphone but ipad shwoing orange screen also It will not go 0.

Comment: while putting constraints for universal application you have to take care of constraints type for example, if you want your view to behave the same as iPhone than you should try putting constraint like `Aspect Ratio` according to the placement of other views and objects.